How to assign stdout of subshells to variables in a platform agnostic way
I have discovered that on Sun 10, /bin/sh does not support $(...) syntax for variable assignments, with or without double quotes:
-bash-3.2# uname -a
SunOS unknown 5.10 Generic_147148-26 i86pc i386 i86pc
-bash-3.2# /bin/sh
# x=$(echo a)
syntax error: `x=$' unexpected
# x="$(echo a)"
# echo $x
$(echo a)

The desired behaviour can be achieved using backticks, like this:
# x=`echo a`
# echo $x
a

However, I believe it is undesirable to use backticks, as to my understanding, backticks are deprecated for all Unix shells (please correct me if I am wrong about this - this is my reference).
My question is, is there a simple platform-agnostic way to assign the stdout of subshells to variables, such that it will work for Sun 10's /bin/sh and for other Unix shells?

slm's closing line is on-point here: "After reading all this you should have the take away that you're strongly encouraged to use dollar parens unless you specifically require compatibility with a real original non-POSIX Bourne shell" (just like the one you're using now)
